# What is the difference between "mound" and "hill"?

Tags: meaning

I learned these words have similar meaning. While reading a book. the writer uses these two words for different meaning. I want to know the difference of meaning. Is there any difference?

Comment: The OED is not very specific about 'mound'. Many of the uses are 'rare', 'obsolete' or 'historic' (also 'metaphoric'). Bank, embankment and dam are all included in the word it would seem. It appears to be a bit of a vague word, which is why this is a comment, not a proper answer. There is also the 'mound of Venus' to think about, as well.

Answer (score 1):

A mound is a hill that is or appears to have been put there artificially, while a hill represents an elevated location smaller than a mountain. [National Park Service](https://www.nps.gov/scbl/planyourvisit/upload/Geographic-Landforms.pdf)

Show an excerpt of the text for a more precise explanation.

Comment: But your _U.S. Department of the Interior_National Park Service_Scotts Bluff_ article states that a 'mound' _must_ be artificial, whereas [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/mound)  gives the example: " 'The hillside rolls out in mounds against a gray sky, and tufts of grass twirl in the winter wind.' From OregonLive.com"